# chrome.runtime.sendMessage from webpage to chrome extension not return

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

My Chrome extension mv3 receives messages from webpage and replies to it. Here are the codes in webpage to send message to extension:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(chromeExtensionId,
            {
             "Message": "Hello",
             "Data":
             {
              "Name": 'Jason'
             }
            },
            function(response) {
             console.log("chrome.runtime.sendMessage", response);
           });
```

and codes in extension's background.js to receive message and reply with true/false:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(message, sender));
    sendResponse(true);
  });
```

manifest.json:

```
{
   "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
   "action": {
      "default_icon": {
         "16": "images/logo16.png",
         "32": "images/logo32.png"
      },
      "default_title": "My Extension"
   },
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "all_frames": true,
      "match_about_blank": true,
      "js": [ "util.js", "contentscript.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
   } ],
   "description": " ",
   "externally_connectable": {
      "matches": [ "https://*.mysite.com/*", "http://*.mysite.com/*" ]
   },
   "icons": {
      "128": "/images/logo128.png",
      "16": "/images/logo16.png",
      "32": "/images/logo32.png",
      "48": "/images/logo48.png"
   },
   "manifest_version": 3,
   "name": "My Extension",
   "permissions": ["cookies", "tabs", "proxy", "alarms", "storage", "downloads", "webRequest", "notifications", "nativeMessaging", "clipboardRead", "clipboardWrite", "declarativeNetRequest","declarativeNetRequestFeedback" ],
   "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
   "version": "4.0.7"
}
```

Most of the time it works fine.

The only problem is when i set my webpage as startup page of chrome, which means the page is opened immediately when chrome starts, sendMessage does not return and console.log in both sender and receiver sides are not printed. There is no error output in console either. It looks like codes freeze inside sendMessage. What's going on there?

Comment: Seeing the manifest would be helpful, especially the "run_at" property.

Comment: manifest.json added

Comment: Have you tried opening the service worker internals (chrome://serviceworker-internals/) page?  That might provide some additional details.  It has a log and also a checkbox to pause the script on startup for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known problem. Chrome intentionally delays extensions at browser startup to show the active tab faster. The workaround is to repeat sendMessage:

```js
send('abcdefgkhgghfg........', {foo: 'bar'}, res => {
  console.log('response', res);
});

function send(extensionId, msg, callback, retry = 20) {
  const timer = setTimeout(send, 100, extensionId, msg, callback, retry - 1);
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionId, msg, response => {
    if (!chrome.runtime.lastError || !retry) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      callback(response);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: but sendMessage's response callback is never invoked

Comment: In that case it's a bug. You can move setTimeout out of the callback to handle it. See the new code.